# Xamarin Forms SocketsForPCL

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, nuget, portable-class-library

I'm trying to get the SocketsForPCL working on my Xamarin Forms PCL project. I've included the nuget and `TcpSocketClient ( var client = new TcpSocketClient(); )`. The error I get -

> Error: The type or namespace name 'TcpSocketClient' could not be
>   found.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the 'bait and switch' approach, how do I get this this starting?

Comment: Have you included the *SocketsForPCL* package in all your platform specific applications also? If the library is using the "bait-and-switch" technique the library needs to be *explicitly* referenced in all projects that is directly *or* indirectly using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 'using' line was all wrong, tried "using Sockets.Plugin.Abstraction;" Correct is `using Sockets.Plugin;`

Comment: Next time, right click on your erroned keyword and just select the missing using in the list.